# ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, netbeans, classpath, derby, javadb

I'm getting the following error when I try to run a Java class which interacts with Java DB.

I try loading driver with :

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
```

In libraries, "derby.jar" do exist. I'm using NetBeans IDE 6.0.

Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: You should add the error message.

Comment: Always provide stack trace when reporting an error!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you [added](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H8lJVoa8ytI) `derby.jar` to the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

First, open the jar (with winrar or similar app) to make sure that the class is actually there, **under the correct path** !

If it is, then, my friend, you have a classpath issue - add the jar location to the project's classpath - usually you can see the classpath used where running the program in the log/ouput pane so you can make sure it's included.

Good luck !
Danny